# Pandas - calculate rolling standard deviation over all columns

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation, standard-deviation

Say I have a pd.DataFrame and want to calculate the rolling Standard deviation. In pandas I can use `rolling(window=x).std()`, but it gives me the SD by column. I however want the standard deviation over all columns in a given row.

As an example consider the pd dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'col2': [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6], 'col3': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df
   col1  col2  col3
0     1    -1     1
1     2    -2     2
2     3    -3     3
3     4    -4     4
4     5    -5     5
5     6    -6     6
```

When calculating for a window size of 2, for instance, I would like to have the standard deviation in row 2 as the sum of the two rows divided by 6 (or 6-1), doesn't matter), so: np.std([2,-2,2,1,-1,1]).

I tried to calculate it on a melted dataframe, but I didn't get the result as expected:

```
df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index').set_index('index')['value'].rolling(2).std()
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?
I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Note that what you describe by `sum(2,-2,2,1,-1,1) / 6` is the `mean`, not the `std`. Which one do you want?

Comment: thanks! I want the std, it's corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = len(df.columns)
window = 2
out = df.stack().rolling(window * n).std().xs(df.columns[-1], level=-1)
```

out:

```
0         NaN
1    1.643168
2    2.639444
3    3.656045
4    4.679744
5    5.706721
dtype: float64
```

`out` is only std.

you said divide by 6 or 5, so i dont divide anything for you to choose.

Comment: I had this in mind initially, the drawback is that it's computing all intermediates, so for 3 columns you compute only 1/3 of interesting values, for 100 columns you'd have to discard 99% of the computations.

Comment: @mozway i agree

Comment: that is a straightforward solution. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient in my opinion is to use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)'s [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) to form a 3D intermediate and use [`std`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) on it (be aware that numpy's `std` has `ddof=0` by default and pandas `ddof=1`):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

N = 2
out = pd.Series(swv(df.to_numpy(), N, axis=0).std((1,2), ddof=1),
                index=df.index[N-1:])
```

Output:

```
1    1.643168
2    2.639444
3    3.656045
4    4.679744
5    5.706721
dtype: float64
```

As a new column:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

N = 2
df.loc[df.index[N-1:], 'out'] = (swv(df.to_numpy(), N, axis=0)
                                 .std((1,2), ddof=1)
                                )
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3       out
0     1    -1     1       NaN
1     2    -2     2  1.643168
2     3    -3     3  2.639444
3     4    -4     4  3.656045
4     5    -5     5  4.679744
5     6    -6     6  5.706721
```