Rolling standard deviation of all columns, ignoring NaNs
I have the following dataframe:
data = {'a': {1: None, 2: 1, 3: 7, 4: 2, 5: 4},
 'b': {1: None, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 9, 5: 6},
 'c': {1: None, 2: 2.0, 3: None, 4: 7.0, 5: 4.0}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).rename_axis('day')

       a    b    c
day               
1    NaN  NaN  NaN
2    1.0  2.0  2.0
3    7.0  2.0  NaN
4    2.0  9.0  7.0
5    4.0  6.0  4.0

I want to get a new column ("std") with the rolling standard deviation of all column values. NaNs should be ignored. Let's say the number of rows to be included in the rolling window is 3 and min_periods (meaning the number of rows with at least one non-null value) is 2.
This is the expected output:
       a    b    c       std
day                         
1    NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
2    1.0  2.0  2.0       NaN
3    7.0  2.0  NaN  2.387467
4    2.0  9.0  7.0  3.116775
5    4.0  6.0  4.0  2.531939

The first std value (2.387467) is equal to np.std ([1,2,2,7,2], ddof=1).
I tried both solutions proposed here but they don't work properly with my dataframe, probably because of NaNs.

You can use numpy.nanstd for working with missing values:
#source https://stackoverflow.com/a/77704074/2901002
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

N = 3
df.loc[df.index[N-1:], 'std'] = np.nanstd(swv(df.to_numpy(), N, axis=0), (1,2), ddof=1)

print (df)
       a    b    c       std
day                         
1    NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
2    1.0  2.0  2.0       NaN
3    7.0  2.0  NaN  2.387467
4    2.0  9.0  7.0  3.116775
5    4.0  6.0  4.0  2.531939


Thanks. What's the function of "(1,2)" in the nanstd function?

@younggotti - It is parameter axis=(1,2) in numpy.nanstd, reason is because processing 3D array

Another solution:
def fn(idx):
    g = df.loc[idx]
    if g.notna().any(axis=1).sum() < 2:
        return np.nan

    return np.nanstd(g, ddof=1)


df["std"] = df.reset_index().rolling(3)["day"].apply(fn).values
print(df)

Prints:
       a    b    c       std
day                         
1    NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
2    1.0  2.0  2.0       NaN
3    7.0  2.0  NaN  2.387467
4    2.0  9.0  7.0  3.116775
5    4.0  6.0  4.0  2.531939

